# Call one helper function within another helper function in laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel

This is my helper function one which render input field in blade

```
{!! Helpers::render_input('settings[companyname]','Company Name',Helpers::get_option('companyname'),'text',array('autofocus'=>true)) !!}
```

I also tried this way, but it is not working.

```
{!! Helpers::render_input('settings[companyname]','Company Name',self::get_option('companyname'),'text',array('autofocus'=>true)) !!}
```

I am calling other function **Helpers::get_option('companyname')** in above function.Both function individually working fine.So i am finding a way to call one helper function within another helper function in laravel blade.

Is there anyway to call function this way?

Comment: What is the namespace of Helpers?

Comment: namespace is **App\Helpers**.

Comment: Did you make `Facade` of `Helpers`? If not you must insert with `namespace`

Comment: what "isn't working", what do you expect, and what is actually happening?

Comment: @lagbox in **rander_input** function i am calling another function **get_option**, which generates error. If i pass static value instead of **get_option** function it will work fine, so basically i am not able to call one helper function within another helper function in laravel blade.

Comment: @maki10 My helper function is working fine, i call them individually it will run but in this it generates error

Comment: what ERROR are you talking about? ....

Comment: @lagbox Above function is generating error. if i write it as bellow without calling another helper function it will work fine.

{!! Helpers::render_input('settings[companyname]','Company Name','**TEST**','text',array('autofocus'=>true)) !!}

Comment: what ERROR are you talking about? ...